# Show Hide divs in views based on boolean value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an app using Asp.Net MVC and C#. One of the requirement is to check what process the item is and then to only show the appropriate div. So I've decided to create a Table in the Db which consist of:

```
Id     ProcessDescription       DivOneVisible        DivTwoVisible
1      Approved                 True                 False
2      Analysis                 True                 True
...
```

**NOTE - The Id's and ProcessDescription will never change**

Currently the table only holds 10 rows of data but the idea is, in future more rows/columns can be added.

I then go ahead and create the appropriate methods, one for each Div as follows

```
public bool ShowDivOne(int id)
{
   var data = uow.GetRepository<ItemProcess>().GetById(id);
   bool showDivOne = data.DivOneVisible.HasValue ? data.DivOneVisible.Value : false;

   if (showDivOne)
       return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

I use the same code as above for `ShowdivTwo()` method, but match the different column. Then in the view I do

```
@if(ShowDivOne){//div one code here}
@if(ShowDivTwo){//div two code here}
```

This works but I was wondering if there is a more  generic way where I can write one method which will cover each scenarios even if new columns or rows are added.

Comment: You realize you can just do `return data.DivOneVisible.HasValue ? data.DivOneVisible.Value : false;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but i'll still need to write method for each div

Comment: I was just commenting on the (pointless) `if` block in your method :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh ok, i'l ltake your comment into account

Comment: You can use single method containing 2 `bool` properties in a viewmodel and pass both of them, then `if` condition checks passed value on view side.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto would it be possible to provide an example please?

Comment: This all seems a bit odd, particularly have a table which is trying to describe what is shown in a view. By `ProcessDescription` are you referring to the 'status' a document currently has?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes that's what `ProcessDescription` is a status. I'm open to other approaches if you have a better approach than to read from a table

Comment: you can do `join` your `show Hide Permission table` with the `table` from where the div's content coming from and add one more filed to you view model or `bool` type to set the `visibility` of div. Fill the fields on some condition base in query.

Comment: do you need example?

Comment: Why do you need a database table at all. Surely the 'document' has a `Status` property (an `enum`?) so in the view you can just use something like `@if(Model.Status == DocumentStatus.Approved) { ....` etc (or better still have a view model with properties (say) `bool CanViewXX` and `@if(CanViewXX) { ...`)

Comment: @RKSharma if you wouldn't mind please.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The admins want to be able to add the status in the near future hence why I've gone down the table route. The original idea was the `enum` route

Comment: as @Stephen Muecke commented you can also do it with `enum` by comparing `ProcessDescription` property to enum and set the visibility of div but then you have to write little bit extra code with every div

Comment: You can always update your enum :) Making extra database calls for a view specific issue seems a waste of resources

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you still need to have a mapping between Database and ViewModel somewhere. At the moment it is hard coded in your methods.

You can make it absolutely generic if you start use reflection and have a mapping array with properties name. But I would nt recommend doing it as it over complication and hard to maintain and change.
(If you want I can go into details of implementation).

For you example I would suggest to have a viewmodel per item, that contains properties of divs to display.

```
public class ProcessViewModel
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public bool ShowDivOne {get;set;}
  public bool ShowDivTwo {get;set;}

  ProcessViewModel(){}
  ProcessViewModel(ItemProcess data){
    Id = data.Id;
    ShowDivOne = data.DivOneVisible.HasValue ? data.DivOneVisible.Value : false;
    ShowDivTwo = data.DivTwoVisible.HasValue ? data.DivTwoVisible.Value : false;
  }
}
```

You still query for each item individually or query them altogether and pass data to viewmodel to construct it.

And a simple foreach on a view to traverse through the list of viewmodels.

Extending it to contain more properties would be very easy and strait forward, with minimum code to maintain.